# Close a jQuery UI Dialog from an element inside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

Here's a quick question that's probably simpler than I'm thinking.

I'm populating a jQuery UI dialog with the resulting html from an $.ajax() call.  In certain cases that html includes a button that when clicked, I want to close the containing dialog.

Assuming that I don't know anything about the element that was specified to be the dialog using `$("#element").dialog()`...(i.e. I have no idea what the "#element" selector is from the dialog's inner content) - What's the best way to close the dialog from an element clicked inside of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `closest()`

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

Comment: Interesting... it doesn't actually appear that .ui-dialog is the right selector.  Dialog barfs out a few divs, and the one that seems to actually need dialog('close') called on it isn't ".ui-dialog"... still investigating...

Comment: looks like .closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); is what is needed.

Comment: @Womp, yeah, the `.ui-dialog` element is the wrapping element that jQuery puts around the original content to turn it into a dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$('a.close').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: what if the element is nested?

Comment: I was fixing my sample just when you wrote that