# Closing a Jquery UI dialog from inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 pages, say page1.html and page2.html.

page1.html has this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                   $('#mydialog').dialog({autoOpen : false, modal : true});
                   $('#myopenlink').click(function() {
                                             $('#mydialog').load('page2.html');
                                             $('#mydialog').dialog('open');
                                             return false;
                                           });                                 
                   });
```

The relevant HTML elements in page1.html:

```
<a href="#" id="myopenlink"> Open </a>
<div id="mydialog"> </div>
```

when I click "myopenlink", I'll get a modal dialog displaying page2.html.

Now, in page2.html, I have another link (or a submit button etc..). I want to close the dialog once it's clicked (i.e. close the dialog from within the page it loaded).

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

After some digging I guess my question isn't about dialog box specifically. This is what I'm trying to do:

page2.html content:

```
<a href="#" id="mycloselink"> close </a>
```

page1.html content:

```
function closeLinkClicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Please Reach this point so I replace this with close dialog');
}

function doneLoading(data) {
    $('#mydiv').on('click', '#mycloselink', closeLinkClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
                             $('#mydiv').load('page2.html', doneLoading);
                            });
```

page1.html also has this of course:

```
<div id="mydiv"> </div>
```

When I click the link which was loaded from page2 into the mydiv, nothing happens (I expect the alert to show).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$('#myopenlink').click(function(evt){ evt.preventDefault(); $(this).dialog('close'); });`?

Comment: is this the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203977/close-a-jquery-ui-dialog-from-an-element-inside-of-it) ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the same question. I tried the suggested solution and it didn't help. Not sure if that question was talking about loading a .html page inside the box or just injecting HTML to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya like this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mhLc5/6/ **OR Updated Answer =>** this http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/1/

**Dynamic Append** Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/13/

SO to close the dialog you just need to call `.dialog('close')` rest a demo will give you a good place to play around.

APIs reside here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

good read: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/close-a-jquery-ui-dialog-from-the-inside

Hope this helps!

**code**

```
 buttons: {

            'Submit': function() {
                $Dialog_div.dialog('close');
            }
```

**Rest of the sample code**

var $Dialog_div;

```
function fnOpenDialog() {
    $Dialog_div = $('<div id=\'ThisDialog\'>Hello Page 2</div>').prependTo('body');

    $Dialog_div = $('#ThisDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        title: 'Dialog stack overflow HULK',
        modal: true,
        stack: true,
        height: ($(window).height() * 0.95),
        width: ($(window).width() * 0.9),

        buttons: {

            'Submit': function() {
                $Dialog_div.dialog('close');
            }

        }

    });

}

$('#ClickMe').click(fnOpenDialog);​
```

Comment: I want to close the dialog from a HTML element inside the loaded page, not using the dialog buttons.

Comment: @AmirW hmmm do you mean; close dialog box from parent window element? sorry if i sound thick - I just want to make sure I gotchya this time, cheers!

Comment: @AmirW okies not from dialog button but child element? yea? i.e. element inside the dialog box? B-)

Comment: yes. I edited the question, maybe it's more clear now (and more focused to the problem).

Comment: @Amir fixed I reckon; see this - I reckon this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/

Comment: Thanks for the example. The difference in my situation is that the "close" link isn't present in the page from the beginning but is injected in run time, so the click event handler doesn't see it for some reason.  I tried to use .on(), .live(), .delegate() but no luck :(

Comment: @AmirW Here you go man: http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/13/ NOw I have appended the button on the fly. hope this helps

Comment: Thank you :)
The problem was some js code which was somehow pasted into page2.html and ruined everything :(

Comment: All good bro @AmirW glad it helped :) have fun! + 1 to your question

Answer (score 2):

To actually close the dialog box in your event handler use this:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

It will traverse the DOM back up from the newly loaded content into the original div that now has the dialog box wrapping it.

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've posted for actually registering the events, but as far as I can see there's no need to use event delegation here at all.

As you're not performing the registration until after the `.load` has completed, you can register the event handler *directly* on `#mycloselink`.

Comment: please see the edited question. I removed the dialog from the question. Looks like my problem is something basic in event handlers with dynamically generated HTML.

Comment: Yep @AmirW this is right :)) I reckon, if you will use firebug you can inspect the element and you can see this, I fyo want you can use the demo below, and If you want I can remove my post, cheers! :) +1

Comment: @AmirW right, I missed that on first reading - so your actual problem is about event delegation, not dialog boxes?

Comment: @AmirW I reckon this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pb2eR/ is what you want see my post below, yea?